# Difficult Discrete/Probability Problem

Tags: probability, functions, discrete-mathematics

Here's the question:

> For a function $f:[n]\rightarrow[n]$, where $n$ is the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, define the *inverse complexity*, $ic(f)$ as the number of ordered pairs $\langle i,j \rangle$ such that $i<j$ and $f(i) \leq f(j)$. Prove that:$$p\left( ic(f) \geq \frac{n^2}{3} \right) \leq \frac34$$ where
>   f is chosen uniformly at random from the set of all functions.

I'm just stumped.

Comment: have you tried the expectations method ?  get the mean and variance of the number of such pairs & use markovs inequality ?

Comment: Is $f$ one-to-one in $n$?

Comment: No. $f$ is chosen uniformly at random from the set of all functions.

Comment: i replace the $f_i$ with iid U(0,1) to  avoid ties, and believe $E(ic(f) ) = \frac 12 {n \choose 2}$ and variance order of $n^3$.  would have to get the details see how it works out, plus the messy issue of the r.v.s being uniform on 1,...,n.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ic^{\langle i,j\rangle}(f)$ be a Bernoulli random variable which is one if $i<j$ and $f(i)\leq f(j)$, and zero otherwise. 
Note that $ic(f) = \sum_{i,j} ic^{\langle i,j\rangle}(f)$.

Fix an arbitrary pair $\langle i,j\rangle$, $i<j$. 
If $f$ is a random function, there is a chance of $\frac 1 n$, that $f(i)=f(j)$.
Otherwise, by symmetry there is a chance of $\frac 1 2$ that $f(i)<f(j)$. 
In other words,
\begin{align}
E[ic^{\langle i,j\rangle}(f)] &= \Pr[ic^{\langle i,j\rangle}(f)=1] \\
&= \frac1 n + \frac{n-1}n\cdot\frac 1 2\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2n}
\end{align}
Therefore, by the linearity of expectation we have
\begin{align}E[ic(f)] &= \sum_{i,j} E[ic^{\langle i,j\rangle}(f)] \\&= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot \frac{n+1}{2n} \\&< \frac{n^2}4\end{align}
Finally, by the [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) we get 
$$\Pr\left[ic(f)>\frac{n^2}3\right] \le \Pr\left[ic(f)>\frac 4 3 E[ic(f)]\right]\le \frac 3 4.$$